# How can i MouseClickDrag position while holding Ctrl+Windows key ? Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Please, how can i hold Windows+Ctrl key while MouseClickDraging?

Here is the code:

```
Send, {Win Ctrl Down} 
CoordMode, mouse, screen
MouseClickDrag, left, 3181, 326 , 3769, 642
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please describe what you are trying to do in more detail so that we can provide better answers?

Comment: `Send {LWin down}{Ctrl down}` ???

Comment: i want to keep holding the windows and ctrl key and at the same time, while holding the keys i want to drag the left mouse click from one position to another position

Comment: @JoeDF  `Send, {LWin down} {Ctrl down} 
CoordMode, mouse, screen
MouseClickDrag, left, 3181, 326 , 3769, 642 ` it's holding the keys but when it gets to mouseclickdrag it release the holding keys

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the hotkey you use to trigger the logic does not conflict with the keys you want to send, ie. don't use <kbd>Win</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. With that being said, the following example uses <kbd>F3</kbd>. For the <kbd>Win</kbd> key, you need to specify left or right. Since it doesn't seem to be of importance, the example just assumes <kbd>LWin</kbd>.

```
CoordMode, mouse, screen 

F3::
Send, {LWin down}{Ctrl down}
MouseClickDrag, left, 3181, 326 , 3769, 642
Send, {Ctrl up}{LWin up}
return
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still don't know why it's not working, when it gets to MouseClickDrag, left, 3181, 326 , 3769, 642 it releases the holding keys(Windows and Ctrl). I want to mouseclickdrag holding the keys. I'm using screen cippling tool by Joe Glines and i want to perform OCR using Windows+Ctrl + MouseClickDraging

Comment: Is it possible to change the hotkey used for the screen clipping tool?

Comment: yes, i tried changing just to CTRL still having the same problem, if i use the code below when it gets to mouseclickdrag it releases the holding key and then if i manually do mouse click and drag with my mouse it works, it keeps holding the Ctrl key i just dont understand why the mouseclickdrag dont work, why mouseclickdrag is realesing the holding key, i tried using sendevent too.

 `CoordMode, mouse, screen 
F3::
Send, {Ctrl down}
Sleep, 900
MouseClickDrag, left, 3181, 326 , 3769, 642`

Comment: Can you try changing it so something that doesn't have Ctrl or Win either?